# Uso de memoria compartida

Tags: c

Tengo este programa y lo que necesito es que en ves de compartir el dato `char` donde imprime "Somos binarios", compartir un dato entero para realizar una operación matemática. Es decir, realizar la operación en el proceso hijo y después que me imprima el resultado el proceso padre.

```
#include stdio.h
#include stdlib.h
#include sys/shm.h //Memoria compartida
#include sys/ipc.h
#include string.h

#define TAM 1024

int main(){

    int pid,memoriaID,n=50;
    int *punteroAMemoriaCompartida = NULL;
    puts("Vamos a usar memoria compartida con varios procesos");

    if((memoriaID = shmget(1315511,TAM,0664|IPC_CREAT))==-1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error al reservar la memoria");
    } 

    pid = fork();
    switch(pid) {
        case -1:
            fprintf(stderr,"Error al hacer el fork");
        break;
        case 0: //El hijo
            punteroAMemoriaCompartida = shmat(memoriaID,(void *)0,0); 
            puts("Soy el hijo");
            //strcpy(punteroAMemoriaCompartida,"Somos Binarios");
            pmc = &n;
        break;
        default:
            sleep(5);
            punteroAMemoriaCompartida = shmat(memoriaID,NULL,0);
            puts("Soy el padre");
            printf("Texto en memoria compartida: %d\n",*punteroAMemoriaCompartida);

            shmdt(&punteroAMemoriaCompartida);
            if(shmctl(memoriaID,IPC_RMID,NULL)==-1){
                fprintf(stderr,"Error al liberar la memoria");
            }
        break;          
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿  Cual es la pregunta ? ¿ Que problema **concreto** te has encontrado ?

Comment: y si en vez de char lo declaras de tal forma?

Comment: ya lo edite lo edite

Comment: cuando hago eso y le paso el tipo entero en el proceso padre me tira un 0 y no el valor que deberia